# I'm trying to do an automated test on creating a facebook account

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm trying to do an automated test on Facebook by trying to create an account, but I'm having a problem clicking on the "Create Account" button, I'm trying to use a FindElement by id, but it is not working.

```
public void criarConta(String nome, String apelido, String email, String password) {

    driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_2_OE")).click();
    
    WebElement nomeElement = driver.findElement(By.name("firstname"));
    
    nomeElement.sendKeys("Teste");
    
    
    WebElement apelidoElement = driver.findElement(By.name("lastname"));
    
    apelidoElement.sendKeys("Alfasoft");
    
    
    WebElement emailElement = driver.findElement(By.name("reg_email__"));
    
    emailElement.sendKeys("fabio.teste@alfasoft.pt");
    
    
    WebElement passwordElement = driver.findElement(By.name("reg_passwd__"));
    
    passwordElement.sendKeys("AlfasoftTeste_");
    
    
    driver.findElement(By.name("birthday_day")).click();
    
    WebElement idElement = driver.findElement(By.id("day"));
    
    idElement.sendKeys("6");
    
    
    driver.findElement(By.name("birthday_month")).click();
    
    WebElement mesElement = driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
    
    mesElement.sendKeys("Ago");
    
    
    driver.findElement(By.name("birthday_year")).click();
    
    WebElement anoElement = driver.findElement(By.id("year"));
    
    anoElement.sendKeys("1999");
    
    
    driver.findElement(By.id("u_h_3_BO")).click();
    
    
    driver.findElement(By.name("websubmit")).click();
    
}
```

(Im invoking this code in another Class using: `public static void main(String[] args)` throws Exception and then `tarefa2Project.criarConta("nome","apelido","email","password");` ...

Answer (score 0):

You could go for the xpath here, use the element attributes and the text to make it unique:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@role='button'][text()='Create New Account']")).click();
```

Comment: @FábioSantos if your `cssSelector ` worked, so what exactly the problem?

Comment: I wasnt using a cssSelector

Answer (score 0):

In order to not be tied to the element's text and not to use `xpath` you can use the following `css` selector:
`li>a[role='button']`